# Angular Mat Table renderRow() is missing in Angular Material 9.1.3

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have an Angular 9 App and having trouble in calling the method renderRows() in angular material table. The error says renderRows is undefined.

This is my import

```
import {MatTable} from '@angular/material/table';
```

My ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
```

And the function when deleting row

```
    delete(row: any) {
     this.table.renderRows();
    }
```

Please let me know if I miss something. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz where i/we can reproduce?

Comment: Can you show the exact error message? And the html

Comment: Hello @Alvin, did you import ViewChild as well? 

import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';